# How should I works with countries and cities in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I need to store some ads each of them has city and town something like the following:

```
ad
 |- title
 |- desc
 |- country
 |- city
...
```

I can to find ads by city and/or town. So how should I store them in database? In MySQL I used id, but I don't know how should I make this in MongoDB?

**EDIT:** I need to perform the following queries: 
1. Give me all ads by some town.
2. Give me all ads by some country
3. Give me all ads by city and country

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your intending to query for ads keeping it as you have it may be alright. With the schema presently as such you can perform a query like so (nodejs example):

```
orm.Ad.find({city:"New York"}).exec(function(error, ads) {   });
```

This will return all ads containing 'New York' as the city. I don't see any reason from what you have said to have separate collections for known cities and countries.

Edit: When storing data in mongo a unique id is created for the item. You don't have to do this.

If you were to query for all ads for city AND country you could modify your query as such:

```
 orm.Ad.find({$and: city:"New York", country:"united states"}).exec(function(error, ads) {   });
```

Comment: I added another snippet of code which returns only results of the specified city and country. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how could I get list all cities and countries for my form. Should I need to have cities and countries collections?

Comment: I wasn't aware that you were populating a form with the data, so yes it would be more convenient in that case to have separate collections for state and country. You can then save either the state/country name or _id in the ad object.